# How to view topic properties in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

i want to view topic level properties something like

```
"message.timestamp.type": "LogAppendTime",
"cleanup.policy":"compact"
```

is it possible to view what all properties is set at topic level?
is there any command where i can view my topic level properties as mentioned above i google lot and found a cmd but its not work for me

cmd is as follow

```
kafka-configs.bat --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative could be

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test
```

that lists some basic information about the provided Kafka topic, along with all non-default configurations (`Configs`) on topic-level. For example,

```
Topic:my-topic   PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs: compression.type=gzip,segment.bytes=1073741824,retention.ms=100,max.message.bytes=100001200,delete.retention.ms=100000

    Topic: my-topic  Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 1,2,0
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know why you think kafka-configs script is not working.
Remember that the script only print the configurations with a non default value.

If the script only prints something like:

```sh
Configs for topic 'test' are
```

Probably, the topic configuration has not been changed.

> If you are familiar with docker, i recommend you to run a container
>   with landoop/kafka-topics-ui image.
>   https://hub.docker.com/r/landoop/kafka-topics-ui/

It is a usefull docker image that shows all the data of the topics, messages, offsets, configurations ...

Here you can see and example of configuration view:

[image]